# Best practices for renaming files created on Unix which have special characters in Windows?

Tags: windows, unix, special-characters, filenames

I am transferring files on a Unix server to Windows clients. If the filename contains a Windows-special character, such as `"`, I get the following error message, of course: [`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/1bad5853-fca3-4074-ba2f-6f8d7009968d/the-filenamedirectory-name-or-volume-label-syntax-is-incorrect). So I need to choose a different filename.

Are there any conventions or "best practices" for renaming the files so that I filter out the special characters? At the moment I would replace them with underscores or percent-encoded characters, but I'd like to see if I would do better to try something else.

*A side note: I am using Java, so if there are built-in or third-party utilities (of which I am not aware) for solving this problem, references to them would be fantastic. But an agnostic solution is fine.*

Answer (score 0):

try using the backslash before the ' " ' sign like filename/".txt . Try if it works. As backslash in the unix script make any special characters like *, ", & etc unreadable by the shell.

Comment: Do you mean `/` or `\ `? `\ ` is backslash. Also, Windows doesn't allow backslashes in filenames, see the link in my question.